# How to define one route to handle request with page parameter and without it?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I would need one route definition (if it's possible), that will handle both requestes:

- http://www.example.com/list
- http://www.example.com/list/2

First one is displaying first 10 elements of the list, second is displaying second "page" with next 10 elements.

IMPORTANT: I would also like (in View):

```
$this->url(array(), 'list');
```

To create http://www.exaple.com/list URL, and not http://www.example.com/list/1

What I have already is:

```
<list type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex">
    <route>list(?:/(\d+))?</route>
    <defaults>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>list</action>
        <page>1</page>
    </defaults>
    <map>
        <page>1</page>
    </map>
    <reverse>list/%d</reverse>
</list>
```

It handles both request, but creates http://www.example.com/list/1 URL on reverse.

If it's not possible with one route - what is the best way to hadle that kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide null as the default value for page instead of 1, but I don't think this is possible using XML routes as Zend_Config_Xml does not support `null` as a special value (it will interpret as the string 'null').

You can sort of work around this using the standard route class:

```
<list type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
<route>list/:page</route>
    <defaults>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>list</action>
        <page>null</page>
    </defaults>
    <reqs>
        <page>\d+</page>
    </reqs>
</list>
```

The only quirk here is that you will get the string value 'null' as the page param if there is no page variable in the URL.

If you were to use an ini file for routes, or define them in PHP you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: So generally what's the best way to store route config? I always used XML and found it most self explaining. But not having possibility to use NULL value there disqualifies it completely.

Comment: Try the ini format, see if that works better. There is an example of the syntax in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config